# Generate rows till end of the year based on current month's data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having data till current month from 1st day of the year. I have to pick up the current month data and populate the same data by changing the flag till end of the  year

I'm planning to create a union all query, but unable to change it dynamically based on current month.

I'm having a table with 8 columns and 'Flag' as 9th column in which one column is date with Month Year data. The ask is I have to pick the current month data and populate the same data with Month year as upcoming month name till the year end for the remaining 7 columns with flag as 'Future'. What's the best way to do it?. For Example I'm having data from Jan'19 till August'19. I have to copy August'19 data and change the date (Month_Year) field as 'September'19 till December'19 and combine it with original table as it has full year data with actual data till August'19 and copied data of August'19 till December'19

Comment: please add sample data and required output.

Comment: I have sample data in excel and I'm unable to upload it

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add table structure/dataset. you can attach snippet/picture of the table with data as well.[image: Below is a sample structure based on what you mentioned]

*1. Remember that August will have only 21 days data currently.As such you can repeat the last days data for the remaining number of days.
2.You can also try and use FORALL to insert data back to your table, but it might be tricky as month will have to change 4 times*

Based on this a sample code can be:

```
 DECLARE

l_remaining_mnths         NUMBER;
TYPE tab_sho IS TABLE OF sho_table%ROWTYPE
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
l_tab tab_sho;
l_month  VARCHAR2(100);
j        NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT 12 - EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate)
  INTO l_remaining_mnths
  FROM dual;
  
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
  FROM sho_table
  WHERE flag = 'current';
  
  dbms_output.put_line('total records-->'||l_tab.COUNT);

  FOR i in 1..l_remaining_mnths
  LOOP
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,i),'Month')||19
    INTO l_month
    FROM dual;
  
      dbms_output.put_line('l_tab(i).month_year -->'||l_tab(i).month_year);
      
      FOR j IN l_tab.FIRST..l_tab.LAST
      LOOP
        l_tab(j).month_year := l_month;
        
        INSERT INTO sho_table
        (
        month_year
        ,column2
        ,flag
        )
        VALUES
        (
        l_tab(j).month_year
        ,'newvalue'
        ,'future'
        );
      
      END LOOP;
   
    EXIT WHEN SQL%NOTFOUND;
    
  END LOOP;
  /*
      dbms_output.put_line('Before for all');
      FORALL j IN 1..l_tab.COUNT
      INSERT INTO sho_table
      VALUES l_tab(j);
      dbms_output.put_line('after for all');
  */
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('We are in the exception  '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Comment: Can you kindly break it down and let me know what it is doing?I'm unable to understand what the code is doing